# eclipse "TERM environment variable not set"

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have build a C program in Eclipse on Linux(Ubuntu MATE).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int num = 100,d1,d2,d3;
  system("clear");
  while(num <= 500)
  {
    d1 = num % 10;
    d2 = (num % 100) / 10;
    d3 = num /100;
    if(num == (d3*d3*d3) + (d1*d1*d1) + (d2*d2*d2))
      printf("%d \n", num);
    num = num + 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I don't get any error when I build it, but when I execute it by pressing the run button, it says

> "Error exist in required project.Continue launch?"

Then I press the yes button and it gives following output in the Eclipse console:

```
153 
370 
371 
407 
TERM environment variable not set.
```

But when I execute this program in a real terminal then it runs fine and gives following: 
[image: output]

here is output in text :-

```
153 
370 
371 
407
```

But here the line "TERM environment variable not set." is not shown. It only occurs in eclipse terminal. Why is this happening?

Also can i use real mate terminal instead of eclipse console?

Comment: Post text as text, not images!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is probably from `clear`. In order to send the correct sequence to the terminal for clearing the screen, it needs to know the terminal type and uses the `TERM` environment variable for it. In eclipse, you don't have a real terminal and no `TERM` variable is set.

That being said, don't execute `clear` from your own program. It forks a process for no gain, is not portable to non-*nix platforms, breaks the assumption that a normal tool will just write output and not delete anything, and, as you see, depends on the environment.

If you really need control over the terminal as a screen, have a look at the [`curses` library](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses).

Comment: please ,i have added new line at the end of my question,can i use my real terminal instead of eclipse console in eclipse?if yes,then how?